# Add Thumbnail to List View

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I was trying to add thumbnail to list view but the problem is that  nothing gets displayed.here is the code

```
System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog open = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
open.Filter = "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF|" + "All files (*.*)|*.*";
open.Title = "Add Slide Show Image";
open.ShowDialog();

BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
logo.BeginInit();
logo.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
logo.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
logo.UriSource = new Uri(open.FileName);
logo.EndInit();


image.Add(logo);

listView1.ItemsSource = image;

listView1.Items.Refresh();
```

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <Border Padding="5,2,0,2">
            <StackPanel Width="289" Orientation="Horizontal"  >
                <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderThickness="4" Margin="0,0,4,0" Height="80" Width="80" Background="{x:Null}">
                    <Image  Stretch="Fill"  Source="{Binding image}" />
                    <Border.BorderBrush>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.9,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF00C4FF" Offset="1" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF093D5C" Offset="0.089" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.BorderBrush>
                </Border>
                <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderThickness="4" Margin="-85,0,4,0" Height="80" Width="80">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.9,1.2" StartPoint="0.1,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="#4EFFFFFF" Offset="0" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#49FFFFFF" Offset="0.163" />
                            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.472" />
                            <GradientStop Color="#3DFFFFFF" Offset="0.457" />
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                </Border>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

[image: A screenshot]

Comment: look at the output window for binding error

Comment: Yeh i see error there it says image property nott found in object.It means that the items source that i am giving to it does not have image property.so what can i do to show list of BitmapImage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a class

```
 class MyImages
    {
        public BitmapImage image {get;set;}
        public  String Name {get;set;}
        public bool IsChecked  {get;set;}
    }
```

Now create a `List<MyImages> myImages = new List<MyImages>();`

```
BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage();
logo.BeginInit();
logo.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
logo.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
logo.UriSource = new Uri(open.FileName);
logo.EndInit();

myImages.Add(new MyImage(){image = logo, Name = "SomeName", IsChecked = true });

listView1.ItemsSource = myImages;
listView1.Items.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

If `image` (in your code) is a collection, you've created a collection of `BitmapImage` objects.  Your template binds to to `image`, `Name`, and `IsChecked` properties, none of which are properties of the `BitmapImage` class.

You *probably* want to make an `Image` property in your view model class (the one that has `Name` and `IsChecked` properties), set the `Image` on each of those objects, and then bind the `Source` property in your template to the `Image` property in your object.